# Advanced Pseudo Random Bit Generation

Tags: c#, random

Well I want to generate pseudo-random bits for a mathematical problem. The Bit size is user fed. But unlike normal problems there's a small twist here. The mathematical problem also gives valid results if the bits begin with 0's and literally match the size input by user.
Example: For User Input 4, all the following are valid outputs:

```
-> 0000
-> 0001
-> 1000
-> 0100
```

etc.
I am using this function to generate the numbers now:

```
int randomChoice = choice.Next(1 << (input - 1), (1 << input) - 1);
bitSize = randomChoice;
```

Is there any other way of random bit generation that may begin with 0's as long as it follows the literal bit length in C# without going into complex array manipulation?

Comment: Hey @Jeet.Deir - nice to see you again on SO! The example that you gave, that's not really for input = 4 - is it?! Can you please verify that part?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: 1 << (4 - 1) is the same as 2 ^ 3 = 8, and (1 << 4) - 1 is the same as 2^4 - 1 = 15 which means randomChoice will be an integer between 8 and 15..

Comment: @Miky Dinescu Good to see you too :) That IS for the input value being read Miky. I know your code is perfectly in sync with what I wrote with my if-elses but is it possible with precceding 0's as I posted in the question? Thanks.

Comment: @John Saunders Sorry again. Bad habit :( .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line:

```
int randomChoice = choice.Next(1 << (input - 1), (1 << input) - 1)
```

for `input = 4` is equivalent to:

```
int randomChoice = choice.Next(8, 15);
```

Which will [per MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) pick one of the following values: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 - randomly. Notice that the value 15 *will not* be picked as the documentation states clearly that the lower bound (8) is )inclusive_ while the upper bound (15) is *exclusive*.

Those values in binary are:

```
8 : 1000
9 : 1001
10: 1010
11: 1011
12: 1100
13: 1101
14: 1110
```

I believe what @Jon Skeet was saying is that you are generating random numbers that always have the MSB (left-most bit) set. And are thus missing out on all values that fit in 4 bits that would start with 0 (have the MSB unset).

I would also point out that you should probably include value 15 here, since that also fits in the 4 bits. So, with the two modifications, the line of code should read:

```
int randomChoice = choice.Next(0, (1 << input));
```

That would generate all values from 0 to 15, inclusive:

```
0 : 0000
1 : 0001
2 : 0010
3 : 0011
    ...
13: 1101
14: 1110
15: 1111
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Exactly. Just Is there a way to fill the blank leftward bits with 0's so that I can pass (say for input = 4 and random number = 2) 0010 istead of just 10? That's what I am asking. Thanks again Miky.

Comment: 10 is the same as 0010 (in binary) - just like 2 is the same as 0002 in base 10. If you would like to format the string by pre-pending 0s if the number is less than 4 in size then you could using the String.Format function. Look it up ;)

Comment: Did this: `string binary = Convert.ToString(bitSize, 2);
            if (input >= 0 && input <= 16)
            {
                binary = binary.PadLeft(input, '0');
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
            }`

Answer (score 2):

In your previous question, you accepted an answer that improved your original code.  Problem was, your code was wrong to begin with.  You want only a *single* random bit.  You'll need to do it like this instead:

```
   int maxBit = AskUserForMaxBit();
   int randomBit = choice.Next(1, maxBit+1);
   int randomValue = 1 << (randomBit - 1);
   return Convert.ToString(randomValue, 2);
```

Comment: That makes two of us, I don't get what you don't get.  Pretty sure this is what you actually asked for.  Try it.